Inject AWS SSM parameter value into Webpack build process
I am building a fairly simple website using Webpack. I am using the build-in templater that comes with the HtmlBundlerPlugin plugin to build the HTML page. This works fine
  plugins: [
    new HtmlBundlerPlugin({
      entry: [
        {
          import: './src/views/index.html', // template file
          filename: 'index.html', // => dist/index.html
          data: { customer_name: 'foo' }, // pass variables into template
        }
      ],

I would like the value foo above to be a value from an AWS SSM parameter /bar/foo. I have written the JS to retrieve the value for it but I am just not sure how to clue the two together
import { SSMClient, GetParameterCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-ssm"; //ES6+ Modules import with the command GetParameterCommand

async function get_ssm_parameter(ssm_parameter_name) {
  const input = {
    Name: ssm_parameter_name,
    WithDecryption: true,
  };
  const client = new SSMClient();
  const command = new GetParameterCommand(input);

  const response = await client.send(command);
  console.log(response)
  return response
}

get_ssm_parameter("/bar/foo")

Any help on how to run a JS function to inject the return value into the HTML that would be great

Sounds like you need (and may need to write) a webpack loader/plugin that will make that call for you.  I'm not sure how common a use case it is to store something in SSM but want to expose it in client-side code...

Setting aside the question of why you want to decrypt values from SSM and expose them in client side code (I assume you are OK with having these values visible in the browser, because they will be):
You could create a webpack plugin to do this.
inject-ssm-data-webpack-plugin.js
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
// This is your script to fetch from AWS...
const {getSsmParameter} = require("./access-ssm")

class InjectDataPlugin {
  apply(compiler) {
    compiler.hooks.compilation.tap('InjectDataPlugin', (compilation) => {
      const hooks = HtmlWebpackPlugin.getHooks(compilation);

      hooks.beforeEmit.tapAsync('InjectDataPlugin', (data, callback) => {
        getSsmParameter("my-ssm-parameter").then((response) => {
          data.html = data.html.replace('<placeholder>', response.Parameter.Value);
          callback(null, data);
        }).catch((error) => {
          callback(error);
        });
      });
    });
  }
}

module.exports = InjectDataPlugin;

webpack.config.js
...
const InjectSSMDataPlugin = require('./inject-ssm-data-webpack-plugin');
...

module.exports = {
...
  plugins: [
    ...
    new InjectSSMDataPlugin(),
    ...
  ],
...
};

You'd need to make sure your local AWS config was set up so that your SSM script can do its thing, but the above plugin should replace your placeholder string with the retrieved value.
This is a simple example that fetches one value with a hardcoded name, but you could add a constructor to the plugin that accepts a parameter name, or better yet: an object with key-value pairs that are placeholder-replacement text pairs.  Then your fetching function could grab the values needed for each placeholder and do the appropriate replacements.
You can make it as fancy as you want to...this same approach could be used to fetch data at build time from any service or database and use it to modify your build output.
Webpack docs on creating a custom plugin

This looks great, thanks Matt. Will try it first thing tomorrow.

thank you for all your input. I am getting the error '[webpack-dev-middleware] Error: TypeError: getSsmParameter is not a function' but I am confident this is down to my code. I have only been using JS for a few days now.
Seen the complexity of this solution I am sure my approach is incorrect and need to find a better way. I have a website template and would like to add values like API DNS (values stored in AWS SSM) to the HTML/JS at build time. This would seem like a standard requirement but this my first time building a front end so will need to figure it out thanks again Matt

@alexis that sounds like you're not correctly exporting the getSsmParameter method.  You can either export it like export {getSsmParameter} for a named export, or export default getSsmParameter for a default export.  More here, good luck
